# Displaying specific values from last entered row in database in real time without refreshing the webpage

Tags: php, html, jquery

I tried to retrieve the temperature value from the last entered row in my database and change it when there is another row that has been added without refreshing the webpage. So far the temperature.php file didn't have any problem, but my index.html cannot fetch the temperature.php using the jQuery.

**temperature.php code:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mlxdb');
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `mlx` ORDER BY `mlx`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 1");

$print_data = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);

$data = [
    'studentTemp' => $print_data[1],
];

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

[This is the result of my temperature.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUSvt.png)

**index.html code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Temperature</h1>
    <p>
      <strong id="studentTemp">0</strong>
    </p>
    <script>
      function startLiveUpdate() {
        const textTemperature = document.getElementById("studentTemp");

        setInterval(function () {
          fetch("temperature.php")
            .then(function (response) {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
              textTemperature.textContent = data.studentTemp;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }, 1000);
      }

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoader", function () {
        startLiveUpdate();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[This is the result the I got from my index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feBrW.png)

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: did you check your console ? any error there ?

Comment: I think the problem is not in your backend side. It’s in your js code! try innerHTML instead of textContent Or console log it in the second then part to figure out if it’s working or not

Comment: I found something that works from this post, https://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html. It's not the best but at least it worked. Thank you for the replies though.